# Updating UITableView when underlying SQLite DB changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have `UITableViewController` view which is using SQLLite DB as datasource to build its rows, like below.

I have also `UIViewController` which update the SQL Lite DB, which `UITableViewController` uses. However, it doesn't update the `UITableView` because I assume it will know about the changes when it query the SQLLite.

The problem I notice the app **"sometimes"** crash when i switch quickly from the `UIViewController` - after adding entry in the SQL lite DB - to `UITableViewController`.

I'm new to objective C and iOS, but I know in Java/Android. in such case, I need to inform the view  that there is a change in the underlying data source (using notify). otherwise a crash/error might happen.

Do I need to do the same in iOS, and how do I do that?

```
- (int)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
    MyAPPAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAPPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return [appDelegate.dataModel countMessages]  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fetching the records from the database, just write following line which `reloads` the `table data` with new records.

```
[tbl reloadData];
```